# Warp result of GDAL translate jpg to geotiff using osgeo.gdal

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, osgeo

I am attempting to warp a geotiff created from `gdal.Translate` where the original file was a jpg. I first obtain the ground control points from a co-located text file. The results of `gdal.Translate` yield an image like: [image]

This image is obviously unusable, so I then attempt to use `gdal.Warp`. However, the resulting warped file is completely black and unable to be displayed in QGIS, although the file size is significant.

Below is the code I am using. I am hopeful I have some minor misconfiguration. I have exhausted a search on the GIS stack exchange, GitHub, etc. Any help is appreciated.

```py
from osgeo import gdal, osr

gdal.UseExceptions()

jpg_file = "2023_07_31_213052705_00_00_V_cool_file.jpg"
txt_file = "2023_07_31_213052705_00_00_V_cool_file.txt"

file_name = jpg_file.split(".")[0]
output_tif = f"{file_name}.tif"
warp_tif = f"{file_name}_warped.tif"

# Get GCPs of form X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt from text file
# Example text file output:
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  5.000000, 5.000000, 47.714661, -114.422200, 916.839967
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  5.000000, 1075.000000, 47.526073, -114.453670, 827.612844
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  387.000000, 5.000000, 47.715721, -114.379840, 896.425018
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  387.000000, 1075.000000, 47.522718, -114.446152, 900.318516
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  769.000000, 5.000000, 47.707372, -114.337673, 960.056277
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  769.000000, 1075.000000, 47.520055, -114.438708, 940.681125
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  1151.000000, 5.000000, 47.692140, -114.299220, 1086.532831
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  1151.000000, 1075.000000, 47.517205, -114.431610, 994.127358
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  1533.000000, 5.000000, 47.699168, -114.239725, 1015.314682
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  1533.000000, 1075.000000, 47.514571, -114.424622, 1038.481855
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  1915.000000, 5.000000, 47.713648, -114.159824, 879.999437
# GCP X, Y, Lat, Lon, Alt :  1915.000000, 1075.000000, 47.511863, -114.418013, 1090.940518
gcps = []
with open(txt_file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("GCP"):
            coords = line.split(":")[-1].strip()
            gcp = [float(coord) for coord in coords.split(", ")]
            gcps.append(gdal.GCP(gcp[3], gcp[2], gcp[4], gcp[0], gcp[1]))

# Create a SRS
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

# Create a georeferenced GTIFF from image
opts = {"GCPs": gcps, "outputSRS": sr.ExportToWkt(), "format": "GTIFF", "noData": "0"}
ds = gdal.Open(jpg_file)
out_file = gdal.Translate(
    destName=output_tif,
    srcDS=ds,
    **opts,
)
ds = None

# Warp resulting GTIFF
opts = {
    "resampleAlg": gdal.GRA_NearestNeighbour,
    "polynomialOrder": "1",
    "format": "GTIFF",
    "dstSRS": sr.ExportToWkt(),
}
warp_file = gdal.Warp(warp_tif, output_tif, **opts)
```

Comment: Add 4 corner GCPs first and add more one by one. I believe that some GCP has bad values. I believe that I would play first with gdal_edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html for avoiding self  made errors in coding, but if you trust yourself just do it your way.

Comment: I also do not believe that first order polynomial is good for those GCPs. Try also second or third order polynomial, or thin plate spline.